# how much you expect to spend on pizza based off the number of people that come

Tags: python

You throw a last minute party. You invite 49 other people, which means that the maximum number of people you might need to feed is 50. However, you are not sure how many out of those 49 people will come.
You look at the price list of a nearby pizza place for food called Little Sicily.
It goes as follows: 1-5 pizzas are $20/pizza. 6-10 pizzas are $15/pizza. Lastly, anything above 10 pizzas is $10/pizza. There is also a $5 delivery fee, regardless of how many pizzas are ordered.
You estimate that you need about one pizza per every four people. You can only order whole pizzas and you must order at least enough for everyone.
Write a function called `pizza` that takes the input `people` to determine how much you expect to spend on pizza based off the number of people that come.
Hint:
Use the function 'math.ceil' after importing library 'math' with the following command: import math

```
from math import ceil

people = int(input("Please enter the amount of guests"))

def pizza():
   if people <= 20:
       print (((people/4)*20)+5)
   elif 40 >= people > 20:
       print (((people/4)*15)+5)
   elif 50 >= people> 40:
       print (((people/4)*10)+5)
print(pizza())
```

Comment: I suspect it will be pizza for 1 based on the fact that you've just posted your assignment here. We're not sitting in wait to do your homework for you

Comment: thats a deal @TobiasBrösamle <3

Comment: i pinky promise

Comment: Better try your assignment on your own, and if you have a specific question, come back and ask that specific question. As it is, I'll vote to close.

Comment: i have enterd the code that i have written so fare. i know its wrong, but how can i make it right?

Answer (score 0):

I corrected you code - hope it'll help. The main problem in your code was that you did not took any arguments to your function - so the function did not know how many people wants pizza :D

```
from math import ceil

n_people = int(input("Please enter the amount of guests"))

def pizza(n_people):
    n_pizzas_needed = ceil(n_people / 4)
    if n_pizzas_needed <= 5:
       price = ((n_pizzas_needed*20)+5)
    elif n_pizzas_needed <= 10:
       price = ((n_pizzas_needed*15)+5)
    else:
       price = ((n_pizzas_needed*10)+5)
    return price

print(pizza(n_people))
```